# How to get a File send to my Activity in android?

Tags: android, file

Suppose I have registered my app to open .pdf files now when I click on the file from any explorer my app opens, but how can I access that file?

Comment: By the uri which you get from getIntent().

Comment: Note that it is not necessarily a file. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to handle both `file` and `content` `Uri` schemes.